# PCI-power cable to two molex female connectors

Tags: power-supply, pci-express

I want to put two PCIe cards with molex power connector and ideally one more PCIe card with SATA connector into my computer. Unfortunately, I can not find any power cables from my PSU to power the cards.

I have one 6/8 pin PCI connector available. So, I am wondering, is there a cable from 6/8 pin PCI to two molex female (or even two molex and one SATA) connectors? 
I am unable to find such an adapter, it is always just the other way around.

Thank you!

P.S.: It is a T5820 from Dell with 950Watt PSU.

Comment: Unless you already have ton of things plugged in a 950w PSU should have a bunch of spare connectors. Do you have modular power supply and just need to plug some cables into it?  Pics of where the cables come out on the inside of the case from the PSU?

Comment: @cybernard: Yeah, you would think. But it seems Dell highly optimized here ;-) I could obtain a pic, but I think this would dilute the question, as I asked for a specific adapter here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (most likely unwelcome) answer to this question is, that no such adapter can ever exist:

- a Molex or SATA connector carries +5V and +12V
- a PCIe power connector carries +12V only

So it is trivial to create an adapter from Molex/SATA to PCIe, as it just involves ignoring the +5V rail.

A PCIe to Molex/SATA on the other hand would need to create the +5V with the required level of power - this is a PSU job.

Comment: SATA actually is supposed to also have +3.3V  This is why some drives don't work with some Molex to SATA power adapters, they depend on that +3.3V line instead of having an internal regulator for it.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn The 3.3V rail is a misfeature that wreaks havoc with PWDIS-enabled drives. Devices that need it have been deservedly relegated to the scrapheap of history.